# The colour of Naruto‘s Rasengan

Tags: naruto

In the anime it's clearly said, that every one sees the chakra of the Nine-Tailed Fox as red/orange, when Naruto uses it. But no matter what chakra Naruto uses for his Rasengan, it's always blue (like normal). Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Naruto's *own* chakra color is blue, which contrasts with the Nine-Tails' own chakra color of red.

Interestingly though, despite Naruto using the Nine-Tails' chakra to create larger and larger Rasengan, the color remains the same.  This might be a plot hole; this may be indicative of Naruto himself performing the attack with a larger amount of chakra under his control.

Comment: Canonically, [Naruto's chakra color is yellow](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5797/20275) :)

Comment: @Wondercricket:  Is that pic from an official source?  Not seeing any mention of it anywhere on the Naruto wikia, nor has it fit canonically with the story and chakra battles (of note - the tug-of-war he had with the Kyuubi).

Comment: This may be true, but sometimes it‘s said, that he has no chakra left at all. Then he uses the chakra of the nine-tailed and everyone is surpised. In that case, he only uses the red chakra with no blue/normal left so it should be red in my opinion.

Comment: @Makoto I dug around a few sources and discovered this was stated in Chapter 91, page 16ish. This was when Naruto was training with Jiraiya. I wonder why there are inconsistencies

Comment: @Wondercricket I believe it's a mixup with the anime studio, they had to pick a color when animating but forgot to ask the writer of the manga.

Answer (score 0):

Shinobi have chakra that is blue. naruto was not using the kyuubi chakra for the rasengan hence why it is not orange/red.